# Брейкается небольшой тестик на Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Пишу небольшой тестик под Android на Xamarin. Это мой первый опыт с написание подобного рода приложения. В чём ошибка собственно говоря:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace app1
{
[Activity(Label = "Схематехника", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonStart);
        EditText edittext1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.FIO);


        Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonTest1_1);
        RadioGroup RGroup1 = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.radioGroup1);
        RadioButton RButton1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1_1);
        RadioButton RButton2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1_2);
        RadioButton RButton3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1_3);


        button1.Click += delegate 
        {
            int count = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(edittext1.Text, out count);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Test1);
        };


        button2.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Test2); };
    }
}
}
```

Программа останавливается при клике button2 с ошибкой

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Всё задекларировал правильно! Ссылка указана на существующий элемент, всё есть в коде... Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка?

Comment: что происходит с тестом?

Comment: @Grundy отладчик доходит до строки `button2.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Test2); };` после чего выбивает ошибку

Comment: и? ну дошел он до строки, что в этом необычного? предлагаешь угадать, какая именно ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Grundy в том то и дело, что нет. Я сталкивался с ошибками ссылок, сейчас всё указано правильно, задекларировал тоже...

Comment: Все очень просто: ты получаешь _System.NullReferenceException_ в вопросе по ссылке выше рассматривается как его исправить. если данное исключение возникает, определенно у тебя что-то не так

Comment: А в строке `Button button2 = FindViewById...` чему равно `button2`? Если `null`, то к чему остальной код?

Comment: Я лично сомневаюсь, что `сейчас всё указано правильно`. Если бы было правильно - ошибки бы не возникло.